# Secure server accessing R repository

Tags: networking, firewall, whitelist, secure

*Disclaimer: Please forgive my complete ignorance and lack of knowledge with this subject. I am not an IT professional nor do I have experience with secure networks/servers or R. I just happen to be the person roped into this and am completely lost. I was sent here from StackOverflow because this apparently a server issue and not an R issue.*

I work at a university and we have a secure server with very limited internet access (only allowed to navigate to an approved university file sharing site). Some of our researchers use R on the secure network, but with no access to CRAN, they have to write the R code to pick the packages and dependencies, I run the code on my work computer, then upload the R packages to the server using the file transfer site. Even then, only some work because the versions of R are different, which should be a simple fix of just updating the version on the server.

IT has asked me to help them figure out the range of IP addresses to whitelist to allow R on the server to connect to CRAN to download and install packages directly to the server. With no experience, I can't figure out how to code a question to reach out to the R community/volunteers.

Has anyone tried and succeeded at getting a whitelist of IP addresses to access the CRAN site on a secure server or know some kind of workaround that might help my IT team?

If this is completely unclear or ridiculous, I totally understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official list of CRAN mirrors: https://cran.r-project.org

Just pick the one you want to download packages from and resolve its name to an IP address (using `dig`, `nslookup` or even just a simple `ping`).

Comment: Hi Massimo, 

That's super helpful. Thank you!!